# Get the 5 largest key/value in a Javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm new to Javascript and looking for the best performing way to get the keys of the 5 largest values in a object into a new object.

eg, the object:

```
let object= {
  a: 5, 
  b: 87,
  c: 4,
  d: 33,
  e: 5, 
  f: 99,
  g: 1,
  h: 10,
  i: 3,
  j: 43,
};
```

would return

```
object= {
  b: 87,
  d: 33,
  f: 99,
  h: 10,
  j: 43,
};
```

I know this can be done by just looping through each item and comparing with each other, but wondering if theres a better way of doing this in Javascript for performance.

Thanks,

Comment: The process is intrinsically iterative; there's no escaping the need to look through the properties and collect the largest values.

Answer (score 2):

I would convert them to a map, sort them then take the first 5 and convert them back to an object, here is a step by step breakdown:

```js
const object= {
  a: 5, 
  b: 87,
  c: 4,
  d: 33,
  e: 5, 
  f: 99,
  g: 1,
  h: 10,
  i: 3,
  j: 43,
};

const newMap = Object.entries(object);

const sortedMap = newMap.sort((item1, item2) => item2[1] - item1[1]);

const top5Map = sortedMap.slice(0,5)

const top5 = Object.fromEntries(top5Map);

console.log(top5)
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't retain the original key order

Answer (score 0):

> I know this can be done by just looping through each item and comparing with each other, but wondering if theres a better way...

As Pointy said, this process is intrisically iterative, you can't avoid a loop and you can't avoid at least a little inner loop.

Here's a way that minimizes looping, see comments:

```
// Start with an empty array
let top5 = [];
// Add [name, value] pairs to it
for (const key in object) {
    const thisValue = object[key];
    // Is this value greater than an existing one?
    // (This is a small inner loop, hidden in the `findIndex` call.)
    const index = top5.findIndex(([_, value]) => thisValue > value);
    if (index !== -1) {
        // Yes, insert it into the array at that location
        // (There's a small loop hidden here too: copying later entries
        // back one place in the array)
        top5.splice(index, 0, [key, thisValue]);
        // If the array is (now) > 5 entries, remove the last
        if (top5.length > 5) {
            top5.pop();
        }
    } else if (top5.length < 5) {
        // The value wasn't greater than an existing one, but
        // the array still needs values; add it at the end
        top5.push([key, thisValue]);
    }
}
// Convert back to an object
top5 = Object.fromEntries(top5);
```

Live:

```js
let object= {
  a: 5, 
  b: 87,
  c: 4,
  d: 33,
  e: 5, 
  f: 99,
  g: 1,
  h: 10,
  i: 3,
  j: 43,
};
// Start with an empty array
let top5 = [];
// Add [name, value] pairs to it
for (const key in object) {
    const thisValue = object[key];
    // Is this value greater than an existing one?
    // (This is a small inner loop, hidden in the `findIndex` call.)
    const index = top5.findIndex(([_, value]) => thisValue > value);
    if (index !== -1) {
        // Yes, insert it into the array at that location
        // (There's a small loop hidden here too: copying later entries
        // back one place in the array)
        top5.splice(index, 0, [key, thisValue]);
        // If the array is (now) > 5 entries, remove the last
        if (top5.length > 5) {
            top5.pop();
        }
    } else if (top5.length < 5) {
        // The value wasn't greater than an existing one, but
        // the array still needs values; add it at the end
        top5.push([key, thisValue]);
    }
}
// Convert back to an object
top5 = Object.fromEntries(top5);
console.log(top5);
```

Note that `top5` is always in order with the highest value first, to minimize how far into the array we have to go by knocking out `value` early if it's lower than the highest value we know (the first one in the array).

I haven't tried to retain the property order, not least because although properties have order (now), relying on that order is almost always a bad idea.